# "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound"

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I created a bot with C# and deployed it and I keep getting error code `NotFound` or when tested in emulator 404.

The bot works perfectly fine locally when tested but when deployed it fails.

I've created a bot with composer and it does same thing, works locally, but then fails when deployed to Azure.

Bot config  :

[image]

Bot working locally:

[image]

Bot failing remotely:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure web chat testing shows "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395443/azure-web-chat-testing-shows-there-was-an-error-sending-this-message-to-your-bo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I found the solution:
[Error (502) Bad Gateway: When trying to access chatbot deployed on Azure using WebChat channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351005/error-502-bad-gateway-when-trying-to-access-chatbot-deployed-on-azure-using-w)
apparently if you deploy your bot to azure it doesn't work. But if you create a bot on azure, then deploy the bot you created to that appservice it works. The way the answer in the link describes is a little vague and not complete. To resolve my issue I created a bot in azure, and that automatically creates an app service with it. I then published the bot I created in visual studio by selecting the resource group and the appservice as my target of the bot I created in Azure. The bot I want to host then replaces the first bot, and somehow that magically fixes network issues. Apparently if you create  bot in visual studio or composer and publish it as is just doesn't work, this is an issue they need microsoft needs to work on.

Comment: You can create the bot in visual studio using botframework and deploy the app in web app bot or app service because both way you can create the chat bot in botframework. I have updated few more points in my solution please verify and I don't think it's an issue from microsoft side because I have verified all of these in my real world implementation for our customers.

Comment: there's definitely an issue from microsoft side. Createing a bot project via visual studio, then deploying the bot to Azure does NOT work. There's documentation regarding how to publish your bot for C# online and it's about 5 steps. This is supposedly the only way to deploy c# chatbot as stated by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp
However following this exact documentation deploys a bot that doesnt work.

Comment: Even when creating a bot via composer and deploying it via composer it fails. There's an issue with Microsoft's current bot deployment system because it doesnt work. I looked at your solution and it's similar to outdated solutions posted online. Today you can't verify app secrets, and it's not something you necessarily set, it's automatically generated especially if deploying via composer.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue while creating "Web App Bot" with custom password option, sometimes this option will fail. So you can try with auto generated password option in "Web App BOT".

Please verify the following **authentication** details:

1. Microsoft AppId -> Should be use same App Id in both application & azure portal.
2. Microsoft Password -> Should be use same Password in both application & azure portal.
3. Directline Token -> Verify this token if you are connecting from front-end framework.
4. Messaging endpoint -> Verify this endpoint

> **Web App Bot** is help to create all necessary service automatically for chatbot implementation and we can create the same process in another way. Please check the following steps.

- Create an app service in azure ( host your chatbot application )
- Create azure bot channel registration.
- Link App service & bot channel registration using app service endpoint.
- Validate all of the authentication details.

**Note :** You can test your app in azure bot emulator "Test in WebChat" section.

Reference :[Azure Chatbot](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-connect-a-chat-bot-with-azure-bot-service/) &  [Bot Framework Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot)

Answer (score 1):

What solved my problem was changing the Protocol Setting of the App Service. If you've deployed your bot using Bot Composer, in the resource group you will find 2 App Services - one with a 'qna' suffix and the other without. Choose the one without the 'qna' suffix.

Select the App Service --> TLS/SSL settings --> HTTPS Only --> On

[image: Image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the exact same issue after researching I was able to notice that my messaging endpoint was having additional text in it. After removing it. It started working. posting because it may help someone.
[image]